# How to re-call a window running in a thread without closing it?, WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm working in WPF, C#, VisualStudio 2013, and I'm stucking in this problem. I'll explain in steps:

> 1- From the main thread (Windows1) I'd like to display a secondary windows (Windows2). So, I call to my function of thread:

```
 ... CreatethreadWindow(...);
```

To solve this problem I've searched a lot and found the answer, no problem with this point. The code is below ([Reference to this code](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/)):

```
 void threadWindow1(...)
    {
       
        Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            // Create our context, and install it:
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
                new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
                    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

            // Create and show the Window
            Windows2= new WindowsPredefine(param1, param2,..., paramN);
            // Create an event handler to communicate events from windows 2 to the main windows.  
           Windows2.Windows2EventHandler += new RoutedEventHandler(NewDataFromWindows2EventHandler);            
            Windows2.Closed += (sender1, e1) => Windows2.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
            Windows2.Show();
         
            // Start the Dispatcher Processing
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        }));

        // Set the apartment state
        newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        // Make the thread a background thread
        newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
        // Start the thread
        newWindowThread.Start();
    }
```

Notice the line **Windows2= new WindowsPredefine(param1, param2,..., paramN);** where my second windows in created in a background thread.

> 2- I'd like to establish a communication between Windows2 and Windows1. So I made this by creating and `RoutedeventHandler`. So, Windows2 can communicate to Windows1 when it's finished its tasks. The problem arises in step 3.
>
> 3- Now, as Windows2 has already finished its tasks, from Windows1 we want to start again all the process in Windows2 (without closing it), but just changing some of the values of the parameters when we called to the constructor `WindowsPredefine(param1, param2,..., paramN);`

I've tried a couple of things, but any of them works... For example, I've defined Windows2 as global variable, and I've tried to call to the constructor (I've made first public access) from the mainThread, but it don't allow me to re-call a function that is running in a thread from the mainWindow (Windows1).

How can I approach this problem? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Make some of constructor parameters public properties and set/change their value later.

Comment: I'll try but does not works, it is not just set/change the values. I want to re-call all the functions in the constructor.

Comment: What functions? Properties have *setters* for a reason, e.g. you can rise event if property value changes or directly call method.